# What is the algorithm used by SolveAlways function?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

The syntax of SolveAlways function is

```
SolveAlways[eqns, vars]
```

For example,

```
SolveAlways[ax + b == 1, {x}]
```

Mathematica outputs the values of a,b s.t. ax+b = 1 for all x. The function works when eqns are multivariate high degree polynomial equations as well. 
How does this function work? What is the algorithm used? What is its complexity?

Comment: it is really hard to answer such questions in general. As Mathematica is commerical closed source software. So only the Engineers inside WRI really know for sure. From outside, the documentation for the function is all what is available. Also see [WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WhyYouDoNotUsuallyNeedToKnowAboutInternals.html)  `Most of the documentation provided for the Wolfram System is concerned with explaining what the Wolfram System does, not how it does it.`

Comment: For a system of equations it is in effect equating powers in the variable(s) in all equations, and solving for these coefficients equal to zero. Example: `In[1716]:= Solve[CoefficientList[a*x + b - 1, x] == 0]

Out[1716]= {{a -> 0, b -> 1}}`